# Sort Selenium Objects C# - Not A Table

Tags: c#, sorting, selenium

I have some 3 columns on a page and there is a sort button on the page that will sort by date. I have been trying to figure this out with no luck. Below is an example of one record. There may be 50 of these on a page.

How do I get all three "columns" into an array and sort the output by asc or desc order? Then I can click the sort value and get the new array list and compare. If I do a findElements*.toList that will give me a list of all rows but I can't identify the date field in order to sort on.

What am I missing????

```
        |*444577233 444577233 ( WORK 555.123.4567 )* | *Voicemail (1 min 49 sec)* | *Apr 09, 2016 09:42 AM*|

        <div class="full-mailbox-message alert alert-warning" style="display: none;">
        <div id="message-list" class="message-list message-list-scroll">
        <div class="list-item filterable message-item js-message-item cp " data-id="9408">
        <span class="inline">
        <input class="custom js-message-item-checkbox" type="checkbox">
        <label></label>
        </span>
        <span class=" " data-id="9408">
        <i class="message-list-icon icon-voice-mail custom-icon"></i>
        <span class="sender" data-phone="5555551759" title="CONPORT 010,CR3522">CONPORT 010,CR3522 ( 555.555.1759 )</span>
        <span class="time" title="Apr 08, 2016 07:30 PM">Apr 08, 2016 07:30 PM</span>
        <span class="summary">
        <span class="text"> Voicemail (57 sec) </span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-item filterable message-item js-message-item cp " data-id="8592">
        <span class="inline">
        <input class="custom js-message-item-checkbox" type="checkbox">
        <label></label>
        </span>
        <span class=" " data-id="8592">
        <i class="message-list-icon icon-voice-mail custom-icon"></i>
        <span class="sender" data-phone="5555551759" title="CONPORT 010,CR3522">CONPORT 010,CR3522 ( 555.555.1759 )</span>
        <span class="time" title="Mar 28, 2016 08:31 PM">Mar 28, 2016 08:31 PM</span>
        <span class="summary">
        <span class="text"> Voicemail (7 sec) </span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-item filterable message-item js-message-item cp " data-id="8523">
        <span class="inline">
        <input class="custom js-message-item-checkbox" type="checkbox">
        <label></label>
        </span>
        <span class=" " data-id="8523">
        <i class="message-list-icon icon-voice-mail custom-icon"></i>
        <span class="sender" data-phone="5555551754" title="CONPORT 005,CR3522">CONPORT 005,CR3522 ( 555.555.1754 )</span>
        <span class="time" title="Mar 27, 2016 11:45 PM">Mar 27, 2016 11:45 PM</span>
        <span class="summary">
        <span class="text"> Voicemail (7 sec) </span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-item filterable message-item js-message-item cp " data-id="8477">
        <span class="inline">
        <input class="custom js-message-item-checkbox" type="checkbox">
        <label></label>
        </span>
        <span class=" " data-id="8477">
        <i class="message-list-icon icon-voice-mail custom-icon"></i>
        <span class="sender" data-phone="withheld" title="Identity withheld">Identity withheld ( withheld )</span>
        <span class="time" title="Mar 24, 2016 03:51 AM">Mar 24, 2016 03:51 AM</span>
        <span class="summary">
        <span class="text"> Voicemail (1 sec) </span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-item filterable message-item js-message-item cp " data-id="8470">
        <span class="inline">
        <input class="custom js-message-item-checkbox" type="checkbox">
        <label></label>
        </span>
        <span class=" " data-id="8470">
        <i class="message-list-icon icon-voice-mail custom-icon"></i>
        <span class="sender" data-phone="withheld" title="Identity withheld">Identity withheld ( withheld )</span>
        <span class="time" title="Mar 22, 2016 09:59 PM">Mar 22, 2016 09:59 PM</span>
        <span class="summary">
        <span class="text"> Voicemail (4 sec) </span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-item filterable message-item js-message-item cp " data-id="7191">
        <span class="inline">
        <input class="custom js-message-item-checkbox" type="checkbox">
        <label></label>
        </span>
        <span class=" " data-id="7191">
        <i class="message-list-icon icon-voice-mail custom-icon"></i>
        <span class="sender" data-phone="withheld" title="Identity withheld">Identity withheld ( withheld )</span>
        <span class="time" title="Mar 04, 2016 04:53 AM">Mar 04, 2016 04:53 AM</span>
        <span class="summary">
        <span class="text"> Voicemail (4 sec) </span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-item filterable message-item message-unread js-message-item cp " data-id="7074">
        <span class="inline">
        <input class="custom js-message-item-checkbox" type="checkbox">
        <label></label>
        </span>
        <span class=" " data-id="7074">
        <i class="message-list-icon icon-voice-mail custom-icon"></i>
        <span class="sender" data-phone="5555551756" title="cert 1756">cert 1756 ( 555.555.1756 )</span>
        <span class="time" title="Mar 03, 2016 09:03 AM">Mar 03, 2016 09:03 AM</span>
        <span class="summary">
        <span class="text"> Voicemail (4 sec) </span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use DataTable and DataView. First step: add all rows, cell by cell, to DataTable. Then created DataView and sort by the field. Then click sort and create a new DataTable instance and add all rows/cells again. Finally, compare data in each row of DataView and DataTable.
See code below:

```
public void TestSorting()
{
    DataTable table1 = GenerateTable();
    DataView dv = table1.DefaultView;
    dv.Sort = "datetime ASC"; // or "datetime DESC"
    DataRowCollection sortedRows = dv.ToTable().Rows;

    // Click sort here e.g. timeHeader.Click();

    DataTable table2 = GenerateTable();
    DataRowCollection rows = table1.Rows;

    // Compare sortedRows and rows here
}

public DataTable GenerateTable()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("datetime", typeof(DateTime));
    table.Columns.Add("sender", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("time", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("summary", typeof(string));

    IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> rows = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#message-list > div.list-item "));
    foreach (var listItem in rows)
    {
        IWebElement sender = listItem.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.sender"));
        IWebElement time = listItem.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.time"));
        IWebElement summary = listItem.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.summary"));

        DataRow r = table.NewRow();

        string format = "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt";
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time.Text.Trim(), format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        r["datetime"] = dt;
        r["sender"] = sender.Text;
        r["time"] = time.Text;
        r["summary"] = summary.Text;

        table.Rows.Add(r);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Buaban. I will take a look at this tonight when I get home. I played with it for a few minutes and even though I have only 3 rows, sortedRows and rows are returning 113 in the count, It looks like a lot of duplication in the item array and I am not sure why. Running an AreEqual on rows and sorted rows is failing. Much appreciation on the help. I have never seen this process before and it is definitely pretty cool.

Comment: @Dazed Can you post full HTML source? So I can figure out what should be locator for rows.

Comment: When I get home tonight I will add it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a heads up I did not forget about this. The environment bit the dust so they are working on it.  I will post it as soon as I can.

Comment: ok updated the original with some additional. Sorry for the delay @Buaban.

Comment: @Dazed My code should work fine with your HTML. However, I've update CssSelector expresison in my answer with `#message-list`. I've try this on my machine and rows count is 7.

Comment: Thanks Bauban. It seems to be pulling everything correctly but I am guessing my Assert.AreEqual(sortedRows, rows); is not going to fly here. There must be another way to compare the rows. Sorry just have not seen this before.

Comment: @Dazed I think you have to verify value inside the rows instead of compare rows object directly. I usually put value in lists then compare the lists.